# "feel motivating" or "feel like motivating" or "feel like motivated"?

Tags: adjectives

> It can feel **motivating** if you feel you have the power to adapt your responses in ways that produce the outcomes you want.

Why is the form **motivating** instead of **motivated**?

Is it similar to **inspiring** instead of **inspired**

How about the following sentence?

> It can feel *like* **motivating** if you feel you have the power to adapt your responses in ways that produce the outcomes you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why is the form motivating instead of motivated?*

What is the thing that feels motivating? The answer is "it". Clearly "it" is not being motivated, but "it" (despite being a dummy pronoun) can do the motivating. That is why we want the present (active) participle instead of the past (passive) participle.

By the way, "you" (despite not functioning as an object in this sentence) represents the recipient of the motivation. Therefore, we could write:

> You can feel **motivated** if you feel you have the power to adapt your responses in ways that produce the outcomes you want.

---

*Is it similar to inspiring instead of inspired*

Possibly, but I can't be sure without an example.

---

*How about the following sentence?*

That sentence seems unusual to me. It appears to mean:

> If you feel that you have the power to adapt your responses in ways that produce the outcomes you want, then such a situation can make you feel as if you were motivating someone else.

If that is what you mean, then it is correct.

Comment: Fantastic! I really enjoy reading your explanation which meets my needs, just like what a tailor do for a men's clothes. **"manners maketh man"**